# KILL App's MainActivity on Startup if(networkState==false || null)

Tags: java, android, connection

Good day friends of mine.

I want to add a functionality to my **ANDROID** application, which I think it is new to me... but it is new in the development world. The application runs very well at the moment... But I need to add this functionality as explained below.

Please see the sample picture below...which tells exactly what I want to do.

I want to check **network connection** state on **Application Startup**.
If **connection state** is **true**, then, the application should load the MainActivity.xml.
If **connection state** is **false**, then, the application should **return a new String ("Error")** message.

Please see my code sample below...in the onCreate() {} thread.
**NOTE**: *I am not proficient in android development please*.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();//this is line 91...
        Log.d("Network Info", "" + activeNetwork);//log the connection info

        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //initialize the status bar textview control
            statusBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatusMsg);//status bar of the UI
            titleLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);//title text of the UI
```

If the above condition is **TRUE**, the application runs well but if the following condition below is **FALSE**,
the application crashes with ANDROID's error message "*Unfortunately, App has crashed!*". 
Instead of it giving me its own message and crashing, I want to kill the app programmatically using the **else...statement** below.

```
} else {
            data = new String("NO NETWORK CONNECTION! TRY AGAIN...");
            return; //return the message data and kill the APP's UI here
        }
    }
```

Any help will suffice please... I am not well vested in android programming and development...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the reason for crashing is because of misplaced of **super.onCreate** method.

Move this statement outside if block and either you can do a toast message or show an alert dialog.

If above solution didn't work, comment the crash stacktrace.